# Is it possible to make a Venn Diagram in R with one to more relationship?

Tags: r, venn-diagram

| Element-ID | Matched-Element-ID |
| --- | --- |
| 000002F:1277533-1278695 | 000002F:1277851-1278156;000002F:1278168-1278701 |
| 000002F:4883369-4883920 | 000002F:4883369-4883920 |
| 000003F:3696884-3697967 | 000003F:3697075-3697398;000003F:3696884-3697069 |
| 000003F:3715353-3716017 | 000003F:3715353-3715853 |
| 000003F:3728140-3728473 | 000003F:3728140-3728473 |

I have this table (that's only a part of the whole table) that shows one genetic element being assembled into one or more elements of another analysis the problem is that I want to make a Venn diagram out of that. But I'm having a problem assimilating how to set more than one relation to one element.

I could only make this plot, which is clearly wrong:
[image]

If helps I have tables with more information about the elements:
first dataset
[image]

second dataset
[image]

Comment: Hi Yago! Seeing as this question hinges on the datasets, it would be great if you could share a *minimal reproducible* example with data and code. You say the plot is "clearly wrong", but we have no way of knowing if that is actually the case

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you @Mark, I'm going to rewrite the question. Thanks for the patience